# clicking an ipyvuetify button programmatically (part 2): Why .fire_event('click', None) does not work

Tags: python, ipyvuetify, v-btn

I would like to know why one of the answers to this question is not working.
[run programmatically an ipyvuetify button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053418/run-programmatically-an-ipyvuetify-button)

A user said:
looking at the description of the v.Btn class I found this :

|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Methods inherited from ipyvue.VueWidget.Events:
|
|  fire_event(self, event, data)
|
|  on_event(self, event_and_modifiers, callback, remove=False)
I then assume that

```
b.fire_event('click', None)
```

should do trick

But this is not the case.
When doing

```
import ipyvuetify as v
b = v.Btn(children=['this btn'])
help(b)
```

indeed  fire_event(self, event, data) exists but it is not called as such:

```
b.fire_event('click', None)
```

ERROR:
99 def fire_event(self, event, data):
--> 100     self._event_handlers_map[event](self, event, data)

```
KeyError: 'click'
```

How can you use this function of the button?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the event function to call.

```py
def function_to_print_hello( widget, event, data):
    print('hello')
    
b = v.Btn(children=['this btn'])
b.on_event('click', function_to_print_hello)
b

b.fire_event('click', None)
```